# Parsing XML response

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, string

I  got  an  XML  response  as:

```
 <Resp>
<status>00</status>
<errorcode></errorcode>
<errordescr></errordescr>
<data>
    <Table>
        <USERNAME>Name</USERNAME>
        <ACCLOCK>N</ACCLOCK>
        <EMAILID>Samplemail@gmail.com</EMAILID>
        <LASTLOGINDATE>23-03-2015 12:35:40</LASTLOGINDATE>
        <LOGINSTATUS>N</LOGINSTATUS>
        <MOBILENO>9848022338</MOBILENO>
        <PASSWORD>Abcd@1234</PASSWORD>
        <PWDCOUNT>0</PWDCOUNT>
        <PWDVALIDTO>12-05-2015 12:18:10</PWDVALIDTO>
        <DESCRIPTION>Shop Person</DESCRIPTION>
        <STATUS>Y</STATUS>
        <USRID_FK>100017</USRID_FK>
        <ROLE>12</ROLE>
        <COUNTRY>61</COUNTRY>
        <MERID_FK>100002</MERID_FK>
        <GENDER>0</GENDER>
        <COUNTRY1>61</COUNTRY1>
        <STATE>0</STATE>
        <DOB>12-02-1997</DOB>
        <STRID_FK>10025</STRID_FK>
    </Table>
</data>
```

I am saving this XML response in the following `string`:

```
string response;
```

I  want  to  split  the string response and get values of some tags (EX:-`USERNAME`, `STRID_FK`, `MERID_FK`), to save it in other strings for  further usage.

Please help me with this ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, this time using Linq to Xml:

```
var yourXml = XElement.Parse (response); // Parse the response

// Look up specific values by name:
var username = yourXml.Descendants().First(node => node.Name == "USERNAME").Value;
```

Yet another option is to put all the data from `<Table>...</Table>` into a dictionary for easy lookup later:

```
var dict = yourXml.Descendants()
                  .Where(node => node.Name == "Table")
                  .Descendants()
                  .ToDictionary(node => node.Name.ToString(), node => node.Value);

// Look up value using "USERNAME" as key:
var exampleUsername = dict["USERNAME"];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString);

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/data/Table");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string USERNAME= xn["USERNAME"].InnerText;
  string STRID_FK= xn["STRID_FK"].InnerText;
  string MERID_FK= xn["MERID_FK"].InnerText;
  Console.WriteLine("Name: {0, {1}, {2}", USERNAME, STRID_FK,MERID_FK);
}
```

or if try directly to select node 
`xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/data/Table/USERNAME")` or

```
XmlNodeList nodes= doc.GetElementsByTagName("USERNAME");
```

Comment: Thaks  for  your  kind  reply..                                                                        I am  trying  this  in  Windows  Phone  App...  XmlDocument  and XmlNodeLIst  classes  are  not  available.                                                  Even Adding  Namespace  [ using system.xml ].. also  no  efefct in  it...  All references  are  included...Can  you  help?