# Split Xml Response which has repeated nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dictionary

first see  this question and  the  Accepted answer of   [Split  XML  Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226451/split-a-string-which-contains-xml-response)   it  worked  for  normal modes

but  my next  requirement  is  to  split  Repeated  nodes of  Xml  response  to  DIctionary..

my  XML response

```
     <Resp>
    <status>00</status> 
    <errorcode>0</errorcode> 
    <errordescr>Success</errordescr> 
    -  <data>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000116</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100101</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>52000</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>45</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>1420001</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>30/04/2015 10:04:13</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000115</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100100</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>1500</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>13</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>141000</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>30/04/2015 10:04:41</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000118</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100105</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>543</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>1</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>123333</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>05/05/2015 06:26:08</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000123</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100109</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>5454</PRICE> 
  <SKUID>565555</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>06/05/2015 09:11:06</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000112</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100097</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>2000</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>3</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>120002</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>08/05/2015 05:03:29</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000114</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100099</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>23321</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>4</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>32000</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>14/05/2015 07:57:23</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000107</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100095</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>7999.60</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>5</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>160002</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>14/05/2015 07:58:31</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000104</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100087</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>900000000.50</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>1</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>120001</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>15/05/2015 04:02:59</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000124</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100086</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>67867</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>1</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>34567678</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>15/05/2015 10:55:46</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000108</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100094</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>5000</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>10</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>160005</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>15/05/2015 11:37:08</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000125</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100126</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>40.90</PRICE> 
  <SKUID>909090</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>19/05/2015 09:45:04</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000121</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100107</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>2342324</PRICE> 
  <SKUID>234324234</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>20/05/2015 05:29:18</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000117</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100089</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>100</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>122</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>121212</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>20/05/2015 05:29:21</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_STOREITEM>
  <ITMSTRID_PK>1000105</ITMSTRID_PK> 
  <ITMID_FK>100088</ITMID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <PRICE>15200</PRICE> 
  <STCKLMTCNT>4</STCKLMTCNT> 
  <SKUID>121234</SKUID> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <MODIFIEDDATE>20/05/2015 07:14:53</MODIFIEDDATE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_STOREITEM>
- <POS_ITEMTAX>
  <TAXID_FK>10073</TAXID_FK> 
  <ITMSTRID_FK>1000108</ITMSTRID_FK> 
  <STATUS>Y</STATUS> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_ITEMTAX>
- <POS_MAPDISCOUNT>
  <DISID_FK>100223</DISID_FK> 
  <STRID_FK>10070</STRID_FK> 
  <DISPRODUCT>1000105</DISPRODUCT> 
  <DISTYPE>I</DISTYPE> 
  <DATAEXISTS>N</DATAEXISTS> 
  </POS_MAPDISCOUNT>
  </data>
  </Resp>
```

i tried  serializing   by XELEMENT  class  and  getting  value  of  each  node...

```
 - var SDvar = SDresponse.Descendants().First(node => node.Name ==
   "status").Value.ToString();
```

but  it  is  difficult  to  serialize  for  multiple  repetitive  nodes

how  to store  them  in  dictionary as  it  has  multiple nodes with same  name(POS_STOREITEM>..
after  storing  in  DICTIONATY..i  need  to  store  them  in  DB  using  for  loop  for  every  repeated node..please  help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each of the `POS_STOREITEM` elements and get a dictionary for each?

```
foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("POS_STOREITEM")
{
    var dictionary = item.Descendants()
        .ToDictionary(e => e.Name.ToString(), e => e.Value);

    // do something with dictionary
}
```

It would be helpful if you posted questions showing what you have tried and where you have stuck, as this isn't a code writing service.  What I've done above isn't a huge leap from the answer you've already got.